# How do I find an array item with TypeScript? (a modern, easier way)

Tags: typescript

### Is there a canonical way to find an item in an array with TypeScript?

ES6+ allows this simple/clean approach

```
[{"id":1}, {"id":-2}, {"id":3}].find(myObj => myObj.id < 0)  // returns {"id":-2}
```

TypeScript implements many ES6+ features and continues to do so. It seems likely it has at least as nice a solution, so:

**How can an item be found in a array using TypeScript, considering ease of use, modern best practices, and elegance via simplicity?**
*(restating the question slightly to seek best approaches)*

Notes

- "**item**" could be a JavaScript object, or almost anything else.  The example above happens to be to find plain ol' native JS objects, but many scenarios exist.
- "**canonical**" is just a fancy way in Computer Science (and other fields) to say "general accepted rule or standard formula" (remember everyone here didn't know that at some point)
- **This is not about new features**. Any version of JS could do this. However the form to do so gets less and less appealing the farther you go back in time.
- [TypeScript roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) for reference.

Comment: And what kind of object? I don't see an example here. Also, TypeScript is just annotated JS. You can write vanilla JS in TypeScript and it will still run.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer Updated example to show searching for native JS objects.  I know TS supports ES5 code, the point is that the example from ES6 is much nicer, and TS is supposedly on the path of implementing ES6 features.

Comment: @Alexander Abakumov thanks for the edit. Let's keep improving!  Unless you see a disadvantage, I'm going to add to your edits, to address the word "object" within the body text.

Comment: @whitneyland: Sure! Sorry, I should have been changed to the 'item' within the body text as well, not only the title.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer responding to your concerns back when, I should have noted I endeavored to address all of them, and it's now all reflected in edits to the question. If I missed anything, shout out.  Thx for the feedback.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Part One - Polyfill

For browsers that haven't implemented it, a polyfill for `array.find`. [Courtesy of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
```

Part Two - Interface

You need to extend the open Array interface to include the `find` method.

```
interface Array<T> {
    find(predicate: (search: T) => boolean) : T;
}
```

When this arrives in TypeScript, you'll get a warning from the compiler that will remind you to delete this.

Part Three - Use it

The variable `x` will have the expected type... `{ id: number }`

```
var x = [{ "id": 1 }, { "id": -2 }, { "id": 3 }].find(myObj => myObj.id < 0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the type definition be: `find(predicate: (T) => boolean) : T;`? If it is returning `Array<T>` then `filter` can be used

Comment: @Steve Fenton beautiful answer thank you.  Please consider upvoting the question because I think the content is useful, but some ankle biters downvoted before I could clarify.

Comment: Use `find(predicate: (value: T) => boolean): T;` in the interface to get type safety in the predicate

Comment: @Sohnee used this yesterday, and found that  `predicate: (value: T)` instead of `predicate: (T)` is the only way to get strong typing in the lambda predicate.  Don't know why `predicate: (T)` doesn't.  Using TS 1.7

Comment: Why isn't this supported out-of-the box? :(

Comment: @Fenton where is the best place to put the polyfill and the interface definition ?

Comment: @wal it depends on your set up, but polyfills are best included at a high level, i.e. you want to ensure it is loaded before any dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

For some projects it's easier to set your target to `es6` in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    ...
```

Comment: Note that this will break older browsers.

Answer (score 13):

Playing with the tsconfig.json
You can also targeting es5 like this :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "target": "es5"
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You did not read all of the post, there i just let what you should have focus on.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use underscore library.

Install it:

```
   npm install underscore --save
   npm install @types/underscore --save-dev
```

Import it

```
   import _ = require('underscore');
```

Use it

```
    var x = _.filter(
      [{ "id": 1 }, { "id": -2 }, { "id": 3 }],
      myObj => myObj.id < 0)
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need some es6 improvements not supported by Typescript, you can target es6 in your tsconfig and use Babel to convert your files in es5.

Comment: Downvoting because `.find` is an API addition and therefore adding another transpiler is uniquely unhelpful.

Comment: It works with babel-polyfill. But you are right, babel doesn't do it natively with presets.
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443652/7478972