# array.find doesn't work with Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm transpiling my ES2015 code using Babel. However it doesn't translate `find` for Arrays. The following line throws the error `TypeError: options.find is not a function`

```
let options = [2,23,4]
options.find(options, x => x < 10)
```

Comment: it does mention about not fully supporting it on the babel docs, try adding https://github.com/paulmillr/Array.prototype.find

Comment: Shouldn't it be `options.find(x => x < 10)` by the way? It works in babel repl.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: I got the error on IE11 only. Chrome and FF work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use babel polyfill.

```
require("babel/polyfill");

[1, 2, 3].find((x) => x >= 2);
// => 2
```

See: [Polyfill · Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)

Or you can use callback. `Array.find(arr, callback)`

```
Array.find([ 1, 2, 3 ], (x) => x >= 2);
// => 2
```

[`Array.prototype.find` doesn't work in the runtime · Issue #892 · babel/babel](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T892)

Comment: In Babel version 7.4.0 `babel/polyfill` is deprecated in favour of `core-js`.

The same fix can be applied via `import "core-js/features/array/find";`

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions it's

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
```

source: [Babel Docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/#usage-in-node-browserify-webpack)

Answer (score 3):

Or if you're using ES6 imports already

```
import 'babel/polyfill';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just concatenate your javascript files with Gulp or Grunt, you can add the script before your javascript files: `node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js`.

Do not forget to install it: `npm i babel-polyfill`.