# Does babel have a preset to polyfill map, filter and include?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I'm looking through here (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-member-expression-literals) but can't seem to find them.

Comment: map and filter are accepted by default by all browsers, including IE9. For `array.includes`, i guess, yes. Babel polyfill has a polyfill for it

Comment: Ah yes, unfortunately i'm running some code on an ancient runtime.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401513/array-find-doesnt-work-with-babel). Also, for polyfill, you can refer to MDN pages. They usually have them at the bottom. Also, just out of curiosity, what runtime are you running it in? Please tell me its not IE8

Comment: haha no, its duktape 2.3.0.

Comment: I do see them now yeah https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-array. I just need need to sort out how to get babel to polyfill them for me.