# Array.prototype.find Interface Extension raise issues when including Module

Tags: typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, typescript1.8

As far as i'm going in learning Typescript i'm facing an issue.
First of all, i implement this [Array Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455805/find-object-in-array-using-typescript/31457683#31457683) in my single **app.ts**. Due to multiple reasons i'm doing it !

My project's code going bigger and bigger i decided to create my **first module**. I've created a new file called ***whatever.ts*** :

```
export class Foo{...}
```

and i import this module in my **app.ts** like this :

```
import * as whatever from './whatever'
let Foo = new whatever.Foo();
```

But at this point, my previous [Array Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455805/find-object-in-array-using-typescript/31457683#31457683) looks giving some troubles to my old code.

```
class KeyValuePair<T, U> {
    public key: T;
    public value: U;

    constructor(key: T, value: U) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Dictionnary<T, U> {
    private _keyValuePairs: Array<KeyValuePair<T, U>>;

    constructor() {
        this._keyValuePairs = new Array<KeyValuePair<T, U>>();
    }
...
}
```

Each time i'm using an Array function/method intellisense is screaming :

> [ts] Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'Array< KeyValuePair< T, U >>.'
>
> any

This happens each time i try to use :

```
this._keyValuePairs.splice(...
this._keyValuePairs.indexOf(...
this._keyValuePairs.length
for (let kvp of this._keyValuePairs) {...
```

If you need an example try with this method : (also have others advertisement on this one)

```
public keys(): Array<T> {
    let keys = new Array<T>();

    for (let kvp of this._keyValuePairs) {
        keys.push(kvp.key);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Everything okay if i'm not importing a module. Did i fail my first module ? Is this issue known ? (:I didn't find anything on it.) Or is their a good and properly way to code my app with multiple files or am I just stuck and will have to code in a single file as long as i will use this Array.prototype.find Extension ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a Plunk for your code?

Comment: Sure, try this [one](https://plnkr.co/edit/AWMslva1YPLASlNz21aj)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Playing with the tsconfig.json, targeting es5 like this :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "target": "es5"
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You gave up to soon and came to an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: It was just a simple workaround, please check at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455805/find-object-in-array-using-typescript/37394204#37394204 for more. Or answer with your own solution would have been usefull.