# Angular2 find does not exist on Array

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-5, typescript2.0

I have an angular2 project (2.0.0)  using typescript 2.0.4.

I have this code:

```
var assignedIds: Array<string> = this.AssignedUsers.map(u => u.id);
var users = this.AllUsers.filter(all => all.id != assignedIds.find(id => id == all.id));
```

I'm getting an error on the find method:

> Property 'find' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

I get this error on several arrays - not just this one.  A couple are number[], one is string[], and one it a custom object.

If I compile to es6 it works but I need to target es5.

Do I need some typings?

Comment: You need a polyfill (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455805/find-object-in-array-using-typescript)), as you do anytime you want to use an es6 feature (like Array.find) in an environment that only supports es5

Comment: Do I need to make a polyfill?  I thought Angular2 had a solution for this that didn't require custom code.

Answer (score 2):

`find()` did not exist in ES5, so you get the error. You can solve that with a [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455805/find-object-in-array-using-typescript) (as mentioned in a comment).

However, you actually should simply your code:

```
var assignedIds: Array<string> = this.AssignedUsers.map(u => u.id);
var users = this.AllUsers.filter(all => assignedIds.some(id => id == all.id));
```