# Angular 2: Array.find is not a function

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

```
selected: Array<{ object: Mill | Paver | Vehicle, marker: L.Marker }> = [];
```

This is the array I want to do a find on.

```
select(object: Mill | Paver | Vehicle) {
    if (!this.selected.find(o => o.object === object)) {
        if (object instanceof Paver || object instanceof Vehicle) {
            this.selected.push(this.getTripsFromPlanning(object));
        } else {
            this.selected.push({
                object: object,
                marker: this.mapService.addMarker(object.location, object.name, false, 0)
            });
        };
    }
}
```

When I call this function it returns this error: this.selected.find is not a function.

How can I fix this?

edit:

typescript version is 2.0.10

tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Obviously `this.selected` is not an array. Have you tried `console.log(this.selected)` to figure out what `this.selected` actually is?

Comment: In angular 2 you have to use Array.filter instead of Array.find.

Comment: What ? You can use Array.find in angular2 as well

Comment: Why should this be related to Angular2 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: console.log(this.selected) doesn't return anything

Comment: Used Array.filter instead and got the same error, but it said filter instead of find

Comment: can you show the tsconfig and also what is the typescript version?

Comment: @user3197825 What do you mean with "doesn't return anything". It doesn't return anything only when it's not called, but in this case you wouldn't get an error message as well.

Comment: I added the typescript version and the tsconfig file

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it's like it's saying that it is undefined, but that can't be it, right?

Comment: Sure it can be. I guess you are using `function () { ... }` instead of `() => { ... }` somewhere and `this.` is not pointing to where you expect it to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455805/find-object-in-array-using-typescript does this help?

Comment: is Array.push working?

Comment: @SurajRao Array.push is working and after the push console.log(this.selected) returns [object Object]

Comment: print it this way : `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selected,undefined,2))`

Comment: @SurajRao [
  {
    "object": {
      "id": 0,
      "shortCode": "",
      "name": "",
      "shortName": "",
      "location": {
        "lat": 0,
        "lng": 0,
        "date": "2016-12-29T09:14:35.312Z"
      }
    },
    "marker": null
  }
]

Comment: Fixed it! It was my fault. I reffered to this.selected somewhere else and that turned it into something other than an Array