# How to use Array.find() in Typescript Transpiling to ES5

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, gulp

I'm trying to do this in typescript:

```
var component = components.find(c => c.Id == 5);
```

**Error**: *Property 'find' does not exist on type any[]*

I do not want to transpile to ES6.

My Environment:

- Windows 7
- vs2015
- Vue 2.4.2
- In tsconfig.json

  ```
  compiler options:
  ...
  "lib": ["es6"], (this does not work)
  "target": "es5"
  ...
  ```
- using gulp to do build which uses ts-loader  2.3.2
- found this [Find Object in Array using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455805/find-object-in-array-using-typescript) but do not know how to implement pollyfill.

Comment: Try setting the target to es6.

Comment: "*but I do not know how to implement pollyfill.*" - just go to MDN and [use their polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill). Or use really just any ES6 polyfill library, there are many available.

Comment: @Phix that is crazy talk.