# How to get an object with its ID?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a food app which we can customize food like subway. I save items (like sandwich or Salami) and their ingredients (like mustard or bbq) in the shopping cart thank's to their IDs.

The data in my shopping cart are saved like that :

```js
menuSelection: MenuSelection = {
  id: 0,
  supp: [1123],
};
```

The menu looks like this :

```js
  products: Menu[] = [
    {
        id: 0, name: 'Salami', price: 8, hour: null,
        supp:[
          { id: 1123, name: 'fromage', price: 5, hour: null },
          { id: 11234, name: 'bbq', price: 10, hour: null },
        ],
    },
  ];
```

So in my shopping cart I just have the ids and I want to get the object of the food (item and ingredients) how I can do that please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31455805/395461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of `MenuSelection` objects in your shopping cart.

To get the product and ingredients from each `MenuSelection`, you can try the following.

You didn't mention how you want to store the result, so I'm just displaying them on the screen. You can insert them into an array or an object according to your needs.

```js
var products = [
    {
        id: 0, name: 'Salami', price: 8, hour: null,
        supp:[
          { id: 1123, name: 'fromage', price: 5, hour: null },
          { id: 11234, name: 'bbq', price: 10, hour: null },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1, name: 'Fish', price: 10, hour: null,
        supp:[
          { id: 1123, name: 'fromage', price: 5, hour: null },
          { id: 11234, name: 'bbq', price: 10, hour: null },
        ]
    }
  ];

var shoppingCart = [{
  id: 0,
  supp: [1123],
},
{
  id: 1,
  supp: [1123, 11234],
}];

shoppingCart.forEach(menuSelection => {
  let product = products.find(item => item.id === menuSelection.id);
  let foodItem = product.name;
  let ingredients = [];
  
  menuSelection.supp.forEach(suppId => {
    ingredients.push(product.supp.find(item => item.id === suppId));
  });
   
  console.log("Food Item: " + foodItem);
   
  console.log("Ingredients: ");
  ingredients.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you have an `id` and looking for the associated product in the `products` array? It should be something along the lines

```
findProductById = (id: number) => this.products.find(product => product.id === id);
```

Comment: yeah  in the products array and in the supp array of products array but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In this to get the product from the menu you can use

```
findProductById = (id: number) => this.products.filter(product => product.id === id);
```

if you want look into ingredients of that also then

```
findProductById = (id: number) => {
   this.products.filter(
      product => 
      product.id === id || 
      product.supp.filter(ingredients => ingredients.id === id).length
   );
}
```

`product.supp.filter(ingredients => ingredients.id === id).length` this will return length, if length is 0 not match found so false or else length is greater than 0 in case of match found.

If this condition `(product.id === id)` is true then product is found at the top level.